# iOS7 does not detect a Content-Type, when parsing a URL into a HTML5 video element via Javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, html, dojo, html5-video

I'm having an issue where I have a WebView with a video element on it. It looks something like this:

```
<video id="player" preload controls>
   <source id="source" src="" type="video/x-m4v"></source>
</video>
```

when I try to load the video through a javascript file it does not load on iOS device:

```
var player = dojo.byId("player");
player.src="http://trololoexample.com/trololoEndpoint?id=23454325&type=823405"
player.load()
```

also I've tried this:

```
var source = dojo.byId("source");
domAttr.set(source, "src", "http://trololoexample.com/trololoEndpoint?id=23454325&type=823405")
player.load()
```

I get this screen:

[image]

But when I test this in a web browser the video loads fine...

Here are some response headers from chrome, which is expected result (with video loading and playing fine):

[image]

And here is a response header from iPad, which is unexpected:

[image]

also you can see here that it did not recognise the type and shows it as "Other" instead of m4v:

[image]

Can you please help out? Thanks!

Update: same thing happens for .mov files, they do not load too on iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I needed a cert to play media files.

I found the solution here:
https://blog.httpwatch.com/2013/12/12/five-tips-for-using-self-signed-ssl-certificates-with-ios/

Tip # 5: Consider Creating Your Own Certificate Authority (CA)

or

Tip #4 – Creating Self-Signed Certificates with OpenSSL is Easy

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it will help you, but I know the webserver which serves the video file must allow byte-range requests.

If it doesn't then you'll get this "nice" picture.

You might want to look at Appendix A of [this](http://mobiforge.com/design-development/content-delivery-mobile-devices) page if you run a php web server.

Hope this helps

Renaud